# Value of $\int_C\frac{e^z}{z}dz$ with $C$ unit circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

> Compute the integral $$\int_C\frac{e^z}{z}dz$$
>   where $C$ denotes the unit circle with positive orientation.

I was thinking that let $z = e^{it}$, $dz = ie^{it}$, then the integral will become $$\int_C\frac{e^z}{z}dz = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{e^{it}}}{e^{it}}ie^{it}dt$$
$$= i\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\cos t + i\sin t}dt$$
$$ = i\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\cos t} (\cos (\sin t) + i\sin(sin t))dt$$

EDIT: Actually, I did not think that Cauchy Integral Formula would be easy enough to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using Cauchy's Integral Formula?

Comment: I haven't thought about that. Is it like this ?According to Cauchy Integral we have, $\int_C \frac{f(z)}{z - z_0} = 2\pi i f(z_0) = 2\pi i f(0) = 2\pi i$. If it's true, I think it is a bit too simple

Comment: Why would it be too simple? It looks just simple enough. :)

Answer (score 1):

Recall Cauchy's integral formula (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralFormula.html):

$$f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z} dz$$

Let $f(z)=e^{iz}$. Then:

$$1=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz$$

Or

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz=2\pi i$$

Comment: maybe it's a dump question to ask. But if we use Cauchy Integral Formula, we don't need to worry about the "unit circle" or the domain in general. Is it correct.

Comment: @Alexander the domain just needs to be a closed loop containing the point $z_0$.